# How to upload a picture from android client to a custom object salesforce

Tags: force.com, android, insert

I need to insert a picture taken by the phone camera, into a custom object in force.com.  Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I did something a while ago [here](http://peterknolle.com/image-preview-lightning-component/) that is similar and using Lightning. Now we have things like ltng:require to handle the JS loading. You could adapt to non-Lightning with JS Remoting instead of @AuraEnabled.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I working with Native android !